# ExtJS 4.1 - Tooltip within XTemplate

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a treegrid "templatecolumn" that displays an image based on a condition in an XTemplate.

However, I also would like an html formatted tooltip displayed upon mouseover of the image.  I've done this with Ext JS 3.x via ext:qtip metatdata attribute in a renderer, but haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Ext JS 4.1 using tpl and haven't found anything in my searching.

Here's what I have to display the image based on a record value:

```
var myTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate( 
    '<tpl if="p &gt; 0">',
        '<img src="exclamation.gif" height="16" width="16"/>',
    '</tpl>' 
);

var schedTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    ...
    columns:[
        { header:' ', dataIndex:'p',  xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:myTemplate }
    ]
}
```

Has anyone done this or have any suggestions?  Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a method using XTemplate, but this one works for me:

```
{
    text : 'Zdj', 
    width: 40, 
    align : 'center', 
    dataIndex : 'Name', 
    sortable : false, 
    resizable: false,
    renderer: function (v, m, r) {
        if(r.get('leaf')==true) {
            m.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="<img src=services/Images.ashx?id='+r.get('id')+' width=60px height=60px>"';
            return '<img src="services/Images.ashx?id='+r.get('id')+'" width="25px" height="25px"/>';
        }
    }
},
```

In my example I'm showing a bigger image in tooltip, but there is no problem to show HTML formatted tooltip.
You can add conditions to renderer and in my opinion do more that XTemplate can do.

Your small image should go to return line and tooltip content to m.tdAttr.

You can read more about renderer function here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution.  I ended up posting my question on sencha.com and got my answer already: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?223566-ExtJS-4.1-Tooltip-within-XTemplate  Sorry I didn't update this post until now.

Comment: @Alan no problem :) someone prefers XTemplate, someone renderer. BTW helpful link.